# How can I get my angular app to render in ie8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I can't get my application to render in ie8. I've included every shim/shiv that I can possibly think of. Is there something wrong with my html? My application works perfectly in every browser above ie9.

Any helps is appreciated, here is my index.html file below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id='ng-app' ng-app="PredictionApp" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prediction App</title>
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300|Crimson+Text:400,600,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-rangeslider/angular.rangeSlider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/rickshaw/rickshaw.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/allmighty-autocomplete/style/autocomplete.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/r2d3/r2d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-rangeslider/angular.rangeSlider.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/clndr/clndr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rickshaw/rickshaw.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/allmighty-autocomplete/script/autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/allmighty-autocomplete/script/app.js"></script>

    <script src="application.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div class='app-container' ui-view autoscroll="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using custom tags for directives? Any errors thrown?

Comment: I'm debugging in a VM environment for ie8 with firebug lite, some errors are being thrown but they're so vague that I can't pinpoint it. 1 is that Jquery is undefined, another is that "Object doesn't support this property or method". I am using custom element directives, however, not in the default route, therefore it shouldn't be a problem for the home page. There isn't even any html that makes its way into the DOM inside the ui-view.

Comment: Alright, I solved the issue of jquery by using an earlier version. Now I still get an expected identifier or string error.

Comment: Make sure all of your plugins / dependencies are compatible with IE8. Make sure you have no calls to things like `console` hanging around unless you specify them as a function.  Try http://www.jslint.com/ to help find things like  trailing commas `{1:one,2:two,}` that ie errors on.

Comment: @Dylan thanks that fixed that error, but now I'm getting injector module errors.

Comment: you tried your best, there was nothing you could have done. call it. "7/14/2014". RIP IE8

Comment: There are a few weird nuances to check like complete attributes and defaults arrays etc - `angular.module('myApp',[])` and `<html ng-app='myApp'>` - but @dandavis may be right, as of 1.2 they will stop supporting IE8 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.

Answer (score 0):

Your pulling angular 1.3 which they don't officially support. Check the link  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie 
Also You can try angular 1.2, if you are supporting IE 8.